# Sagemaker with Dockerfile

Tags: amazon-ec2, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to automatize [AWS Sagemaker](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) as a base for a large series of deep-learning experiments.

My current approach uses the [Estimators](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html) as the code snippet shows:

```py
import hydra
from omegaconf import omegaconf
from sagemaker.pytorch.estimator import PyTorch


@hydra.main(config_path="setting/", config_name="setting.yaml", version_base=None)
def run_on_sagemaker(params):
    role = "<your sagemaker arn role>"
    estimator = PyTorch(
        entry_point=params.sagemaker.entry_point,
        role=role,
        framework_version=params.sagemaker.framework_version,
        py_version=params.sagemaker.py_version,
        instance_type=params.sagemaker.instance_type,
        instance_count=params.sagemaker.instance_count,
        volume_size=params.sagemaker.volume_size,
        hyperparameters=omegaconf.OmegaConf.to_container(params, resolve=True, throw_on_missing=True)
    )
    estimator.fit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_on_sagemaker()
```

However, when building the indicated [Pytorch docker image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/pytorch/pytorch/2.0.0-cuda11.7-cudnn8-devel/images/sha256-96ccb2997a131f2455d70fb78dbb284bafe4529aaf265e344bae932c8b32b2a4?context=explore), it seems that Sagemaker is not able to install all the dependencies correctly.

Therefore, would it be possible to explicitly declare (through a Dockerfile, for instance) how to create the Docker image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also use the `image_uri` parameter in which you must point to the AWS ECR docker image.

You should find the example available in [Building your own algorithm container](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/scikit_bring_your_own.html#Building-your-own-algorithm-container) very informative.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can install additional dependencies :

1. create a requirements.txt file and add it to the source_dir foler , something like this [example](https://github.com/aruncs2005/falcon-pytorch-fsdp-sagemaker/tree/main/scripts)
   2.You can extend the deeplearning images that AWS provides and install additional dependencies. The available containers can be found [here](https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/master/available_images.md).